# When $\pi+1$ will be a unit provided $\pi$ is uniformizer?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K \supseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ be a $p$-adic field. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring of integer of $K$ and $\mathfrak{m}=(\pi)$ be the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$, where $\pi$ is the prime element or uniformizer of the discrete valuation ring $\mathcal{O}$. Let us consider the $p$-adic valuation (additive valuation) $v$ such that $v(\pi)=1$.
Also let $\mathcal{O}^{*}$  be the set of units of $\mathcal{O}$ defined by $$\mathcal{O}^*=\{x \in \mathcal{O} \ | \ v(x)=0 \}.$$
**Question:**

Suppose we consider the $3$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_3$. Then $p=3$ is the prime element and the maximal ideal is $ \mathfrak{m}=(3)$.

Here $v(3)=v_3(3)=1$ but $v_3(3+1)=v_3(4)=0$, i.e., $p=3$ is uniformizer **while $p+1$ is a unit**.

Now if we se the general situation, $v(\pi)=1$   but $v(\pi+1) \neq 0$ i.e, $\pi$ is uniformizer **while $\pi+1$ not unit.**

Why is so ? What is the crucial part I am missing here?

Am I forgeting the extension field ?

Though in unramified extension the uniformizer doesn't change.

When  $\pi+1$ will be an unit provided $\pi$ is uniformizer ?

Kindly help

Comment: Any nonarchimedean valuation satisfies $v(x+y) = \min(v(x),v(y))$ if $v(x) \neq v(y)$. In particular $v(\pi) > 0$ and $v(1) = 0$, so $v(1+\pi) = \min(v(\pi),v(1)) = \min(v(\pi),0) = 0$.

Comment: @AshwinIyengar, oh, I forgot $v(x+y)=\min \{v(x), \ v(y) \}$ when $v(x) \neq v(y)$. I was thinking only $v(x+y) \geq \min \{v(x), v(y) \}$. Thanks  So for any uniformizer $\pi$, $\pi+1$ is the unit. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that because $|\pi|<1$ it's within the radius of convergence of the power series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$, and so we can write down its inverse as $(1+\pi)^{-1} = 1-\pi+\pi^2-\pi^3+\cdots$ which we see clearly lies in $\mathcal{O}$.